# CompletableFuture runAsync gets error : There is no application attached to current thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1

Tags: java, asynchronous

I use `CompletableFutre.runAsync()` to run the sending of mail notifications asynchronously, but instead of the sending of mails work, it is getting an error `There is no application attached to current thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1`.

```
        // Process Service Request here
        ...

        // Run sending of mail notification asynchronously
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                sendMailNotification(customer.getId(), serviceRequest.getRequestNumber());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                _LOG.error("send notification failed : {}", e.getMessage());
            }
        });

        ...

        // Set UI changes after processing here
```

It is weird since there are similar calls that does not get an error and some did. Seems I only get this error when the sending of mail notification call takes longer (like many recipients, etc). For those sending mails which only have few recipients, it does not encounter this error.

Removing CompletableFuture.runAsync(), will send the mail notification and does not get this error... but it does not process it asynchronously.

I would like to run this async without getting errors, for now, I am thinking of hitting the default timeout thus I am getting this error.

Is there a default timeout for completable future runasync? If yes, how can I increase this timeout?

By the way, I am using JDK8 and upgrading the JDK is not an option.